# Elasticsearch big data

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I`m new in elasticsearch and I have problem.
I have 1 million rows of data and query result take too long.
Went I have 150k it was taking 0.5s , now is taking 10sec. 
Each days, number of data is different (One day can be 150k, other 1 million and etc.)
I need advice how to make it faster.

**Mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "Jobs": {
      "_ttl": {
        "enabled": true,
        "default": "1d"
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "advertiser_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "company_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "feed_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "description_unique": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "county": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "store": true
            }
          }
        },
        "company": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "premium": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "bid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "created": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime",
          "default": "basic_date"
        },
        "updated": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Survey Developer",
            "type": "best_fields",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "boundary_chars": ".,!? \t\n",
    "tag_schema": "styled",
    "pre_tags": [
      "<b>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</b>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "fragment_size": 200,
        "number_of_fragments": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "premium": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "bid": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Server parameters:

- CPU 1 vCPU
- RAM 1 GB
- System Disk 40 GB
- Network 120 Mb/s

Comment: You'll have better chances for good answer if you post here your query and data mapping

Comment: Try to install https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk and run your query - I suppose it will be doing a lot of GC or I/O. If it's so - try to increase your server RAM amount and don't forget to increase ES heap size as well.